# WCAG Compliance - Element with role="button" and no content

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag, wcag2.0

I'm trying to develop a WCAG compliant web app, currently [codesniffer](http://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/) is giving me lots of:

> This element has a role of "button" but does not have a name available
>   to an accessibility API. Valid names are: element content.

From this HTML:

```
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="abcd" role="button"  alt="abcd" title="abcd" value="abcd">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

Setting `alt`, `value`, `title` and `aria-label` seem to do no good. 
How can I have a WCAG compliant element with role="button" with no text inside it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `button` element with the `aria-label` and `title` attributes :

```
 <button class="k-select" role="button"
        aria-label="alternative for screen readers"
        title="alternative for other users"
        value="abcd">
   <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar"></span>
 </button>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. The only problem is that this output is generated by a 3rd party component, so I can't really change the span to a button, I ended up ditching the component and using another one that has built in wcag support.

Answer (score 4):

Adam is right to convert this to a `<button>`. That is the best approach from the start and also means you can dump the `role="button"`. It also means you get accessibility of interaction for free (you don't have to listen for a Space bar or Enter key, for example).

Instead of trying to make the `<button>` itself have the accessible name, put it on the icon. If you do that consistently, you can be certain the icon always has an accessible name, regardless of whether or not it is in a control like a button or a link.

So consider this HTML:

```
<button class="k-select">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar">Calendar</span>
</button>
```

Now you have a normal button that has not been jury-rigged with attributes to try to make it accessible. The icon, on the other hand, has text within it now, and that becomes the accessible name.

Now apply this CSS rule to visually hide that text:

```
.k-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE 6/7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe */
}
```

I usually have this as a utility class (`.visually-hidden`) so that I can apply it wherever.

[FontAwesome talks about an approach similar to this](http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/) on its site for making its icons accessible.

With this approach, you do not need any ARIA, any one-off code solutions, nor any script. This works for your icons first (the real issue) and means when those icons are used elsewhere (links, buttons, etc) they are accessible.

Also, neither `alt` nor `value` is valid for a button. `aria-label` is unnecessary. [Definitely avoid `title`](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/).

Comment: You definitely must set the `title` attribute on the button when hiding text in order to give a correct visible alternative to the icon for 99% of people not using a screenreader, who won't understand what a strange square looking like a schoolbag may significate. We definitely must stop that "visually hide"/"avoid title" politic which does not help the vast majority of users.

Comment: `title` does nothing for users on touch-only displays (or on hybrid displays who are not using a mouse). Only IE10+ displays `title` on keyboard focus. I understand why you want to apply it here, but `title` is an inadequate alternative that causes developers to think they are making something accessible when they are not. The question was about a WCAG fail, and many auditors would fail a button that uses only a `title`. The question also touched on a11y API, and `title` is inconsistently handled by browsers in the API.

Comment: As long as we understand that hiding text does not provide a correct alternative for 99% of users, using both `title` **and** `aria-label` is a solution that will cover far more users. But you're right, definitely, having a permanent visible text is the best thing to do for touchscreen displays when the icon is not sufficient enough.

Comment: @aardrian Great answer. I'm applying this to a different scenario, where I open a link in a new tab target="_blank", to just visually hide the text.